# Texstudio and Nextcloud - "File changed externally" error

Tags: errors, texstudio, cloud

For my thesis at a research institute I am using a internal Nextcloud system to store data online. I figured that if I store my Tex files in Nextcloud I can easily work on my thesis from office and from home without the need of VPN. My Tex editor is texstudio and I am using the Nextcloud client to automatically synchronize my cloud files with my PC and vice versa (just like Dropbox or Google Drive).

However, here is the problem: When I work on a tex file on my private PC and save it, then Nextcloud updates the file in the cloud, but I get simultaneously an error message (see below) from texstudio that the file was changed externally (by Nextcloud it seems). This message pops up and interrupts my workflow. Also quite often I have a file conflict which is occuring due to the Nextcloud synchronisation.

[image]

So far I have two suboptimal workaround: Pause Nexcloud synchronization. This is kind of annoying as I will probably forget to turn it on. Also I will get the error messages from texstudio at least once.
The other solution is to enable the silent reloading option. However, I still get a file conflict error and I can't undo any changes after a silent reload.

I also tried using another editor like TexnicCenter but here I get an error message saying, that I am not allowed to save it.

Did anyone encounter this problem and knows a good solution?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: has the file actually changed?, also I assume you don't want to do what the message you show suggests and allow the file to be reloaded without a prompt?  (I know nothing of nextcloud or texstudion so I can't help with details)

Comment: Hi David, so after saving Nextcloud uploads the file and I guess it then downloads the same file from the cloud and overwrites the existing local file. Probably some metadata changed but the content should be the same. If I click on "No" in the prompt above I receive a file conflict error message when I try saving again.

Comment: yes but why not go to the options and allow reloading?

Comment: I know the use case quite well. I never made friends with Nextcloud, since I also had similar problems with other programs. My solution was to use iCloud, where I never had similar problems and things just work. However, of course, it only is an option if you use Macs. I switched from PC to Mac some 7 years ago and continuously regret that I had not done so earlier. Not really an answer but maybe it helps.

Comment: @ David: When I enable auto-reload I cannot undo any changes. Also my cursor is placed at a different spot after reloading, which is very unconvenient.
Unfortunately my institute only allows me to use their internal cloud service because of data security. I know that with Google Drive for example I don't have these issues.